# Why does my doubly linked list not work? (Pascal)

Tags: pascal

so I have this huge pile of code, but it wont work correctly. And im not sure about how a list works exactly. Can anyone hint me to the right direction who is good at this? THANKS SO MUCH :)

```
Program ListendDerHoelle;

Uses CRT;

TYPE
  Pokemon = ^pointer;
    pointer =
    RECORD
      PokemonName : STRING[30];
      PokemonPosition : INTEGER;
      Next : Pokemon;
      Prev : Pokemon;
    END;
VAR Liste, Eintrag, head: Pokemon;

FUNCTION TraverseList(AddPokemonPosition : INTEGER) : Boolean; FORWARD;
PROCEDURE Ausgabe(i: Integer); FORWARD;
PROCEDURE Abfrage;
VAR PokemonName2 : STRING[30];
    PokemonPosition2, Anzahl, i : Integer;

BEGIN

  Liste := NIL;
  Eintrag := NIL;

  Anzahl := 99;

  Writeln('Wie viele Pokemon einspeichern?');
  Writeln;
  Readln(Anzahl);

  FOR i := 1 TO Anzahl DO
  BEGIN
        ClrScr;
        Writeln('Pokemon Name:');
        Writeln;
        Readln(PokemonName2);
        ClrScr;
        Writeln('Pokemon Position:');
        Writeln;
        Readln(PokemonPosition2);
        ClrScr;

        New(Eintrag);
        Eintrag^.Next := NIL;
        Eintrag^.Prev := NIL;

        IF TraverseList(PokemonPosition2) = TRUE THEN
        BEGIN
              Eintrag^.PokemonName := PokemonName2;
              Eintrag^.PokemonPosition := PokemonPosition2;
              Liste := Eintrag;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
          Writeln('Position nicht gefunden. Das Ende der Welt steht unmittelbar bevor!');
        END;
  END;

    Ausgabe(Anzahl);


END;
FUNCTION TraverseList(AddPokemonPosition : INTEGER) : Boolean;  // Wenn die Funktion also True zurückgibt, ist das Element gefunden!
VAR vElementFound : Boolean;
BEGIN

     vElementFound := FALSE;
      TraverseList := FALSE;


     WHILE (vElementFound = FALSE) DO
     BEGIN

                  IF (Liste = NIL) THEN   // wenn es das erste Element ist
                  BEGIN
                      vElementFound := TRUE;
                      Head := Liste;
                  END

                  ELSE IF ((Liste^.Next = NIL) AND (vElementFound = FALSE)) THEN      // wenn es das letzte Element ist
                  BEGIN
                      Liste := Liste^.Next;
                      vElementFound := TRUE;
                  END
                  ELSE IF (vElementFound = FALSE) THEN  // ansonsten
                  BEGIN
                      IF (Eintrag^.PokemonPosition < AddPokemonPosition) AND NOT (Eintrag^.Next^.PokemonPosition > AddPokemonPosition) THEN
                         BEGIN
                               Liste := Liste^.Next;
                         END
                      ELSE IF (Eintrag^.PokemonPosition > AddPokemonPosition) AND NOT (Eintrag^.Prev^.PokemonPosition > AddPokemonPosition) THEN
                         BEGIN
                               Liste := Liste^.Prev;
                         END
                      ELSE
                         BEGIN
                             vElementFound := TRUE;
                         END;
                  END;
     END;

     IF (vElementFound = TRUE) THEN
        BEGIN
              TraverseList := TRUE;
        END;

END;
PROCEDURE Ausgabe(i : Integer);
var a : Integer;
BEGIN
      Liste := Head;
      FOR a := 1 TO i DO BEGIN


      Writeln(Eintrag^.PokemonName, ' ', Eintrag^.PokemonPosition);
      Liste := Liste^.Next;
      Readkey;


      end;


END;



BEGIN
 Abfrage();
END.
```

Just ignore the end part, i know that it wont produce the right results yet, just the function "traverselist" is interesting

Comment: your list is overriding each iteration isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think your TYPE declaration has got you into a hopeless muddle.  The first thing to do is to sort that out, and then you should find the rest is very simple.

I think you intend the entries in your linked list to be of type `Pokemon`, but it is clearer if you call it a `PokemonNode` for reasons I'll explain..

Now, a singly-linked list is actually a very simple structure: it consists of a series of nodes which each contain data fields (in your case PokemonName and PokemonPosition) and a pointer to the next entry in the list.

A doubly-linked list is like a singly linked list, except that each node also has a pointer to the previous node in the list as well as the next one.

So, you want to define two things, a PokemonNode, which is a single entry in the list, and a PokemonPointer which is a pointer which can point to a Pokemon node.  The way you declare these in Pascal is like this:

```
TYPE
  PokemonPointer = ^PokemonNode;
    PokemonNode =
    RECORD
      PokemonName : STRING[30];
      PokemonPosition : INTEGER;
      Next : PokemonPointer;
      Prev : PokemonPointer;
    END;
```

Btw, I've chosen these names, PokemonNode and PokemonPointer so that if you replace your TYPE declaration with mine, you will have to go through all your code and change it, but more importantly so you have to think about what you are trying to do with the node and the list.

I think you will be able to do the rest yourself, but if you get stuck, ask.  Until you get used to thinking about list nodes, you might find it helpful to draw and label pictures that represent the creation + insertion of a new node and the removal of one.

One tip you may find helpful is to write your list as a circular one (in other words one where the `Next` pointer of the last entry in the list points to the first entry in the list.  This avoids your code needing to keep checking whether the next node is Nil before you do something.  Instead, you just need to keep track of the start of the list, by using a pointer pointed at it.

Comment: wow, awesome! thats a great idea, i will try this out tomorrow!t